# Infinite horizontal Scrolling of UICollectionview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, infinite-loop

I want to achieve infinite Scrolling loop in UICollectionView, with 3 items seen at one time.One item in centre and other two partially seen, thus when scrolls left to right the left item which is partially seen is now shown fully and will be centred thus scrolling will be like a loop.

Guys please help me to find a solution, i managed to make UICollectionView infinite but cant able to centre it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are probably talking about iCarousel. Have a look at [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel).

Comment: Here is a [link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=carousel) where you can find more similar controls.

Comment: Are you constraints locked to the leading and trailing superview?

Comment: I have created a basic implementation for adding infinite scrolling in UICollectionView. Hope it will help you give a start. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/Vishal-Singh-Panwar/InfiniteScrolling)